# Can components or directives be used in both AngularJS and Angular for a hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, hybrid

If I create a hybrid app using ngUpgrade for migrating AngularJS to Angular, can AngularJS directives/services that are "upgraded" still be used on the AngularJS side? Likewise, can Angular components that are "downgraded" still be used on the Angular side?

Reading through the documentation, I found that the two frameworks can be ran side-by-side, but could not find any mention as to whether components could be ran on both sides concurrently.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please explain so I can improve the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, That's not true, I did research. I found that the two frameworks can be ran side-by-side, but could not find any mention as to whether components could be ran on both sides concurrently.

Comment: Well, there is no evidence of that research in the question. Votes (or at least my votes) are based on the question as presented, not on guesses or speculation about what the asker may or may not have done.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, well now you know. I also updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run both of these side by side. Angular has a really nice [document](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) for upgrading from AngularJS(1.x) to Angular. The key point to answer your question is

> One of the keys to a successful upgrade is to do it incrementally, by running the two frameworks side by side in the same application, and porting AngularJS components to Angular one by one. This makes it possible to upgrade even large and complex applications without disrupting other business, because the work can be done collaboratively and spread over a period of time. The upgrade module in Angular has been designed to make incremental upgrading seamless.

Reading through this documentation should help you achieve what you are trying to do.